# Le « tech backlash » : formulation avec l'adjectif ou la préposition et le nom etc. ?

Tags: anglais, prépositions, adjectifs, comparaison-de-langues

> [...] tous reconnaissent qu'après des années d'engouement sans faille,
>   il s'agit maintenant de faire face à un retour de bâton, le « tech
>   backlash ».
>
> [ [*Les géants de la techno tentent de redorer leur blason*](http://www.lapresse.ca/techno/actualites/201801/24/01-5151288-les-geants-de-la-techno-tentent-de-redorer-leur-blason.php), AFP ds. La Presse ]

On peut le comprendre comme étant « the general social [backlash](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/backlash?s=t) [against](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/against?s=t) [technology](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tech?s=t) », il s'agit essentiellement d'une *réaction*, et la collocation peut être d'une certaine manière ambiguë, possiblement dû au fait de l'apport du premier terme au second, mais avec le contexte et l'usage le sens de cet apport est clair (basé entre autres sur la [réponse](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/154772) de Maciej Stachowski, sur *English Language Learners*.).

---

La question n'est pas tant de savoir si c'est le [*contrecoup*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/backlash/564145), le [*mouvement de ressac*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=BACKLASH&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) ou un *retour de [bâton](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/retour_de_b%C3%A2ton)/[balancier](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/retour_de_balancier)* qui traduise le lieux le *backlash* mais plutôt de comprendre comment formuler la phrase qui exprimerait clairement et précisément la notion de *tech backlash* en français...

- Pourquoi trouverait-on ou non l'adjectif ([*technologique*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/technologique))
  adéquat pour exprimer ce dont il s'agit et y aurait-il ambiguïté (serait-ce une [qualification ou une classification](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4304)) ?
- Préférerait-on ou non faire suivre le mot choisi d'une
  préposition, laquelle et pourquoi, et qu'est-ce qui motiverait l'emploi du singulier ou du pluriel avec [*technologie*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tech) ici le cas échéant ?
- Serait-ce suffisant ou faudrait-il d'autres mots pour exprimer sans
  ambiguïté ce dont il s'agit et dispose-t-on d'exemples où l'on a exprimé cette idée autrement qu'avec la collocation de langue anglaise ou la référence directe à une situation passée (*après l'engouement sans faille, maintenant...*) ?

Answer (score 4):

> Pourquoi trouverait-on ou non l'adjectif (technologique) adéquat pour
>   exprimer ce dont il s'agit et y aurait-il ambiguïté (serait-ce une
>   qualification ou une classification)

Il me parait relativement peu adéquat puisque ce n'est pas à la chose technologique en général que s'adresse le retour de bâton mais davantage à l'industrie des nouvelles technologies et ses pratiques.

La difficulté tient dans ce que ce secteur économique a été commodément raccourci en un minuscule *tech* en anglais. En français, il existe bien *la tech* mais elle fait pour l'instant plus allusion à l'écosystème des startups du numérique en France qu'aux géants américains.

> Préférerait-on ou non faire suivre le mot choisi d'une préposition,
>   laquelle et pourquoi, et qu'est-ce qui motiverait l'emploi du
>   singulier ou du pluriel avec technologie ici le cas échéant

Si la tournure suggérée est *de(s) technologie(s)*, là encore cela ne me parait pas idéal (même argument que le point précédent).

> Serait-ce suffisant ou faudrait-il d'autres mots pour exprimer sans
>   ambiguïté ce dont il s'agit et dispose-t-on d'exemples où l'on a
>   exprimé cette idée autrement qu'avec la collocation de langue anglaise
>   ou la référence directe à une situation passée (après l'engouement
>   sans faille, maintenant...) ?

Je vois trois possibilités :

- Employer une périphrase qui reflète le phénomène. Elle sera nécessairement plus lourde et emphatique que l'équivalent anglais. Ex. : *la vague de réaction anti-géants de l'internet*, *le retour de manivelle du numérique*, *la punition des géants de la techno*.
- Trouver un mot composé ou valise qui sera forcément un raccourci plus pauvre sémantiquement. Ex. : *techno-réaction*, *algo-méfiance*, *GAFA-scepticisme*.
- Ce qui se passera probablement si le phénomène prend de l'ampleur : utilisation de l'anglicisme tel quel.

Comment: Tech backlash a besoin du mot contre en français puisque cela veut dire:  ***the backlash against techonology companies***. En format long, cela donnerait: la réaction contre les entreprises technologiques. Backlash = reaction against in English, too.

Comment: Pourquoi "a besoin du mot contre" ? Il n'est pas interdit de rechercher la même concision que l'expression en anglais (qui ne contient pas ce mot)...

Comment: Parce que backlash veut dire, l'acception du mot est une réaction contre quelque chose. Si tu veux ré-écrire, be my guest.  :)

Comment: Merci +1 préfixe _anti-_ comme manière de sublimer la préposition pour ainsi dire ; les choix multiples : la périphrase vs. le mot valise vs. l'emprunt. Merci aussi pour votre lecture attentive de la (des) question(s) et vos commentaires expliquant mon (le) propos.

Comment: Normalement, en traduction, on cherche la notion de base. La notion de base du mot backlash en anglais contient la notion de contre. A reaction against something is a backlash.

Answer (score 2):

C’est bien de réaction dont il est ici question. Une réaction contre un milieu. Quand la réaction s’installe, elle s’organise habituellement aussi.

Comme le terme *réactionnaire* a une tendance péjorative, peu aiment à se qualifier ainsi. Une réaction organisée aura donc je crois tendance à se désigner de *résistance*.

Le français depuis plusieurs décennies déjà accepte et incorpore des mots où le signifiant est placé en dernière position *(géolocalisation, aquaplanage, narcotrafiquant, ...)*. Que ce type de mots ait initialement pénétré la langue sous l’impulsion d’emprunts à l’anglais n’y change plus grand’chose, c’est désormais un modèle accessible.

La réponse de Guillaume31 laisse entendre que le préfixe *tech-* ne représente pas le même concept que son équivalent anglais. C’est possible et je ne connais pas tant le sujet pour prendre position. Je proposerais néanmoins *techno-*, qui me semble plus courant, mais peut-être est-ce une opinion biaisée.

Donc, pour le premier mouvement de protestation, je verrais bien le **techno-rejet**, qui ne serait ambigu que dans la mesure où l’on pourrait penser que l’industrie des nouvelles technologies ait un mouvement à l’unisson contre quelque chose ou quelqu’un. Mais contre qui ou quoi oserait-elle s’élever ainsi bruyamment ? Scénario improbable qui ne laisse que l’interprétation d’un rejet par certains groupes de la course aveugle et effrenée au progrès technologique.

Par la suite, très tôt probablement dans le mouvement, au moment où s’organisent les groupes, on parlerait plus probablement de **techno-résistance**.

Mais tout ceci demeure hypothétique, et je me range à l’opinion de Guillaume31 : si la croissance du mouvement est rapide et explosive, l’emprunt direct à l’anglais est ce qui surviendra vraisemblablement. On pourra alors compter que l’*Office québécois de la langue française* propose sa propre traduction, mais avec un succès que l’on pourrait déjà présumer mitigé.